# A word for “inner protected world”

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What can be the word for "inner protected world"?

I want to use for this title sentence:

> A guy in his **inner protected world**

It's some sort of mental sanctum.

I want to use it in a positive sense. In my local language we call it *cossetto*, the same as when a worm converts itself into butterfly. In my local language we say that it comes out from its *cossetto*.

Like I want to use it for a guy who is happy in his own environment , who doesn't worry about the world situated outside .

Please can someone suggest a better word or phrase?

Comment: Please can you add more information as to what you want "inner protected world" to mean? are we talking about a ring of planets, some sort of mental sanctum, or something interdimensional, or something completely other?

Comment: Yes some sort of mental sanctum :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment to Penelov I think the word you are looking for is [**cocoon**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cocoon).

> **Cocoon** *noun* 2. any of various similar protective coverings in nature, as the silky case in which certain spiders enclose their eggs.

You can use it metaphorically in your sentence:

> A guy in his cocoon

It would imply that he has wrapped himself up and keeps himself away from the world.

Another possible word is [chrysalis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chrysalis), which has a similar meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an introvert ? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/introvert

Or self-enjoyment 
or perhaps the guy is a monk.

Comment: thanks Penelov .. But I want to use it in a positive sense :( do you know any other word? like in local language we call it cossetto . same as when a worm convert itself into butterfly..In local language we call it that it is out from its cossetto :)